# Changing values in a Dataframe

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a dataframe called df1. In df1, I have a column called 'class'. Which looks like this:

```
class
Car
Person
Car
Person
Rider
Rider
Person
Rider
Rider
Rider
Rider
Rider
Rider
Person
Person
Person
Rider
```

Instead of this, I would like to change the strings in the class to integers. I tried the following code to replace the values but it did not change the output.
`df1['class'].replace(['Person', 'Car', 'Rider'], [1,3,5])`

For now, the output is still this:

```
   frameID  trekkingID   x1   y1   x2   y2   class
      913           2  893  544   21   14     Car
      913         107  849  545   10   22  Person
      837           2  912  545   15   10     Car
      837         124  861  547    9   23  Person
      700          81    0  844  273  236   Rider
```

Instead, I would like it to display something like this:

```
   frameID  trekkingID   x1   y1   x2   y2   class
      913           2  893  544   21   14     3
      913         107  849  545   10   22     1
      837           2  912  545   15   10     3
      837         124  861  547    9   23     1
      700          81    0  844  273  236     5
```

Comment: df1['class']=df1['class'].replace(['Person', 'Car', 'Rider'], [1,3,5])

Comment: Thanks hat works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`df1['class']=df1['class'].replace(['Person', 'Car', 'Rider'], [1,3,5])` provided in the comments sections worked!

Answer (score 2):

maybe slightly more extendable (once you get many categories and don't want to have to worry about order between the two lists) is

```
df1['class']=df1['class'].replace({'Person': 1, 'Car': 3, 'Rider': 5})
```

Comment: Ah yes. This is a better idea. Thanks!